# setting text size inside tcolorbox

Tags: fontsize, tcolorbox

How can I set the size of all the text that appears inside a `tcolorbox` to a different size? I have tried `size=small` in the options of the `tcolorbox` to no effect.

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[size=small]
some text
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Comment: This is clearly stated in the `tcolorbox` manual, looking for `fontupper` and `fontlower`, `size=small` has more effects than just the resizing of fonts -- it will influence the box separations etc. as well

Comment: I was a bit confused by the `fontupper` and `fontlower` aspects. Now I know that we can just have `fontupper` without `fontlower` text. initially I had thought both were required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be done by setting a hook at the beginning of the `tcolorbox` environment with the aid of `etoolbox` package. See the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tcolorbox}{\small}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{tcolorbox}%[size=small]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### new solution based on comment

As you mentioned, previous solution makes all boxes' font size small, but with `fontupper` option you can set font size for upper part of `tcolorbox` and with `fontlower` for the lower part.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{fontupper=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[fontupper=\tiny, fontlower=\Large]
This is the upper part. 
\tcblower
This is the lower part.
\end{tcolorbox}

This is normal size font. 

\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But this will set for all the boxes, is there any way to do it for individual boxes? I may want smaller text only for some boxes.

Comment: @Damitr See revision of the solution.

Comment: Ok works perfectly.